# Rails - How to have same image size (resolution) from multiple servers with Cloudinary

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-5, cloudinary

I have a search page result from scraped content in my app, each result have image, from external URL.

**What I am look for :** have exactly the same size for each image, and put each one in Bootstrap grid system.

```
<%= cl_image_tag product.link, :gravity=>"auto:0", :crop=>"scale", class: "img-responsive" %>
```

HTML render :

```
<img src="https:site.com.image.jpg?sw=1920&amp;sh=950&amp;sm=fit">
```

Images have never the same format, like :

- 1920 x 950 px
- 1080 x 1514 px
- 1860 x 2790 px

I am using Bootstrap grid system, so the images have to fit in a **div.col-xs-3** grid system.

My test results are uggly, never gives the same format, quality is deprecated...
I tried resize from Cloudinary, with the cl_image_tag helper but it's always uggly.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you try following the 3 steps here: https://cloudinary.com/documentation/responsive_images#automating_responsive_images_with_javascript

After adding the library (cloudinary-core-shrinkwrap.js) you can just use width auto. for example:
cl_image_tag("smiling_man.jpg", :width => :auto, :crop => :scale, :responsive => :true,
  :responsive_placeholder => "blank")

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks @Shirly